# Conditional Update in SQL row based of of child rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking for a way to conditionally update a parent row based on it's children rows

| id | job | approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1.0 |  |
| 02 | 1.1 | yes |
| 03 | 1.2 | yes |
| 04 | 1.3 | yes |
| 05 | 2.0 |  |
| 06 | 2.1 | yes |
| 07 | 2.2 | no |

The goal would be to mark the parent job (1.0/2.0) as approved if all the child tasks are approved.

Thank you I am not a DBA but have to play one for a bit.

Comment: How do you know what the parent and child relationship is?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your data it appears the jobs that are approved will always have the number of 'yes' rows as 1 less than the number of rows for each job, therefore

```
update T set approved='yes'
from (
    select Floor(job) Id
    from T
    group by Floor(job) having Count(*)-1=Sum(case when approved='yes' then 1 else 0 end)
)u join T on T.id=u.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret the data so that:

- parent `job` ends in `.0`
- all the children have the same initial number
- there is only one level to the hierarchy
- the `job` is a number

Then one method is:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by floor(job)) - 1 as num_children,
             sum(case when approved = 'yes' and job <> floor(job) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by floor(job)) as num_yeses
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set approved = 'yes'
    where num_yeses = num_children and
          floor(job) = job;
```